# Is it possible to generate a non-predefined nanotube in VMD?

Tags: lammps, vmd

I know that generating a Carbon Nanotube (CNT) in VMD, I can get the required LAMMPS input file. Since VMD makes my life way easier, giving me the position, angle and bonding information in the format of a LAMMPS input file, I would love to be able generate my nanotube which has a different lattice structure than hexagonal using VMD. Is that possible with VMD or are there alternative that generate/upload a lattice structure?

In general I am looking for a software to generate for example a nanotube from a triangular lattice or a cubic lattice and has the ability to produce the input file for LAMMPS.

Comment: How did this go Delaram? Have you got an answer? Please update us!